# writing a ifelse() on a faster way (with less memory)

Tags: r, performance, memory

Currently, I'm working on a big data set. The only thing that I do during this task is preprocessing the data.

When I'm running my code, I see that my computers memory increased very fast with this line:

```
binary <- ifelse(subset_variables1 == "0", 0, 1)
```

The only thing that that line should do, is making all my values binary. Can this be done on a quicker manner? Or is this already a good manner (where I have to deal with the memory issues).

Comment: If you need a 0/1 or TRUE/FALSE output, you don't need to use ifelse. Just run the comparison itself and use the logical vector that is returned.

Comment: `binary <- subset_variables1 == "0"`

Comment: FYI, there's actually a faster `ifelse` from `dplyr`: `if_else`

Comment: To continue @docendodiscimus comment, If you want the 0 and 1 just wrap the TRUE/FALSE in `as.integer()`

Comment: Can you explain that a bit more @Sotos

Comment: Try `as.integer(subset_variables1 == "0")`. Converting the logicals to integers translates to 1 for TRUE and 0 for FALSE. If you do `TRUE * 5` and `FALSE * 5` you will see the difference

Comment: And as a side note any integer other than 0 is considered TRUE when converted to logical. You can try it using `as.logical(-3:3)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When working with boolean types and / or conditions, you can use them with mathematical operators and they will be interpreted as `1` or `0` (for `TRUE` and `FALSE`). So `+("0" == 0)` returns `1`, and `1 - ("0" == 0)` returns `0`.

If you have a vector like this

```
set.seed(666)
subset_variables1 <- sample(c("0", "1"), 10000, replace = TRUE)
```

You can use `1 - (subset_variables1 == "0")` to get the required result.

I have compared it to a couple of suggestions in the comments and it is the fastest.

```
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(ifelse = ifelse(subset_variables1 == "0", 0, 1),
               as.numeric = as.numeric(subset_variables1),
               if_else = dplyr::if_else(subset_variables1 == "0", 0, 1),
               plus = 1 - (subset_variables1 == "0"),
               times = 1000
)

Unit: microseconds
       expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
     ifelse 686.668 701.3440 977.0863 910.6570 1170.816 3222.192  1000
 as.numeric 631.813 642.5910 715.8687 677.3830  720.841 1819.925  1000
    if_else 347.409 377.0665 537.3344 482.7055  657.468 1603.241  1000
       plus  97.170  98.8845 129.9091 107.8545  146.303  741.557  1000
```

Comment: For your information: I tried your solution. The results: 
Instead of using 98% memory (old solution), I only use 71% memory now.

Comment: Thank you, that's great to hear!

Comment: A nice little trick: the mean of a vector of logical values is the proportion of TRUE in that vector.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slower but a bit more general solution

```
v <- rep(1,length(subset_variables1))
v[subset_variables1 =="0"] <- 0
```

and a `ifelse` for numeric vectors,

```
ifelse_sign <- function(test,yes,no){

    if(length(yes)==1)yes = rep(yes,length(test))
    if(length(no) ==1)no  = rep(no ,length(test))

    yes[!test] <- 0
    no [test]  <- 0

    yes + no + test *0
}

ifelse_sign(subset_variables1=="0",0,1)
```